# Synonyms to 'so' in this structure: so + adjective + that

Tags: synonyms

> Example: The turnips had been **so** {adjective} that they were coveted.

I tried http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/so?s=t but these don't denote defn. 1 of [so](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/so) as a submodifier, to mean 'to such a great extent'.  I want to preserve this sentence structure and avoid rewrites like:

The turnips had been {adjective}   to a degree/an extent/a manner  that they were coveted.

Comment: You mean like "so *rare* they were coveted", or "... so *hyped* they were coveted", or "so *big* they were covered" or "so *tasty* they were coveted" or "so *well-cultivated* they were coveted"? I don't see anything problematic with constructions like these. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @DanBron Yes, exactly, these all exemplify the example sentence. You're right that nothing is wrong, but I just want to use other synonyms other than 'so'.

Comment: "The turnips, *being quite tasty*, were coveted"

Answer (score 1):

"So" is an [intensifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensifier) and with respect to having synonyms that could simply be "plugged in" as substitutes without changing the sentence structure, it's pretty much a loner.

You could, however, write a similar sentence using so's adverbial "cousin" **such**.

**Such** {ADJ} turnips were coveted.
The turnips were coveted for being **such** a(n) {ADJ} food.

Answer (score 1):

You could flip the sentence around:

The turnips were coveted because they were {adjective} .

Hope this helps